# Including a Symfony bundle from a subtree : how to expand autoload path?

Tags: symfony, autoload

I'm using a bundle from a subtree, so I can't modify the structure nor the placement of it. I currently am trying to get it included in autoloading process, and am failing miserably with the "class not found" error message.
Currently, my project tree (made with Symfony 3.2) is :

```
|- app
|- src
    |- MyappBundle
    |- external
         |- Author
             |-UserBundle
                |- Controller
                |- [...]
                |- AuthorUserBundle.php
```

AuthorUserBundle.php contains :

```
namespace Author\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AuthorUserBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

To include this bundle, I added in app/AppKernel.php :

```
new Author\UserBundle\AuthorUserBundle(),
```

I also added to app/autoload.php, before `AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader` :

```
$loader->add('Author',__DIR__.'/../src/external');
```

I don't master the namespaces imbrications, especially regarding the depth of call, but I tried many variations in autoload.php (like '/../src/external/Author') or AppKernel.php (Author\UserBundle\AuthorUserBundle\AuthorUserBundle()) ending all with the same error message "Class not found".

What did I miss ?

Sorry for the newbie question, I tried alone first, thank you for your time.

P.S. : the `external` directory can't be removed, the git subtree process doesn't allow to operate in a non empty directory.

Comment: Don't use subtree, install your bundle with composer!

Comment: @PatrikKarisch How can I do that if the bundle is in a private repository and can't be publicly available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use git subtree to include 3rd party code. Add a `composer.json` to your `AuthorUserBundle` with all needed autoloading and dependencies. A minimal example (replace `^3.0` with `^2.7` if you still use Symfony 2.7/2.8):

```
{
    "name": "author/user-bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Author\\UserBundle\\": ""
        },
    }
}
```

And require it in your main project as [private repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories). Please add git tags to and follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

Assuming your bundle is then called `author/user-bundle` (composer name), add the following to your projects `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "author/user-bundle": "^1.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@git.example.author/user-bundle.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit 1: added composer.json for AuthorUserBundle repository.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your suggestion. In a SSH way I have to store keys on the computer. Bad news is this computer is shared with many coworkers, I can't let any connection open without asking for credentiels.  
So I tried the HTTP way, but composer doesn't allow http without encryption. I can't install any HTTPS connection to the repository...
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: You can add `"config": {"secure-http": false}` to your `composer.json`. As long this is an internal project, HTTP is not a problem.

Comment: The situation is improving, I'm getting close to what I want & need. First, the composer package is at last included, thanks to your instructions and some trial and error (I had no idea what to put in the external repository's composer.json, hence my edit). Now, the bundle is visible in the /vendor/author/user-bundle directory (which contains among things, AuthorUserBundle.php). But the instanciation `new Author\UserBundle\AuthorUserBundle()` triggers a "class not found" in the AppKernel.php. Any idea what I did wrong ?

Comment: See my edit, you need at least have the autoload section, so composer knows, which parts of your author bundle (in this case the git root of it) gets loaded in which namespace

Comment: Thank you for your time ! It works now. Well no it doesn't, but due to another problem not related to this question (project specific) ;)  *marked as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to `addPsr4` method instead

```
$loader->addPsr4('Author\\UserBundle\\', __DIR__.'/../src/external/Author/UserBundle');
```

Comment: Why someone downvoted you ? It's the solution that worked ! Marked as accepted and upvoted. Your code just miss the double backslash at the end of the first parameter (can't edit less than 6 characters).

Comment: answer edited ! don't know either why i got a downvote :(

Comment: Because the solution is wrong. Never use methods on the loader directly. extra autoloading must be defined in the composer.json

Comment: Theorically yes, but here he's not dealing with a composer package, but with a custom path to include in his autoloading

Comment: Sadly, still wrong. Even if you won't get rid of of the subtree, then you should use the [`autoload/psr-4` section in the `composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4). But the correct way is to get rid of the git subtree and deal with the dependency as a real composer package.

Comment: This solution works, but the best solution is indeed including it as a package with composer.json.